# SQL Query with join and sum

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I want to get the sum of all invoices totals as well as the sum of all items (via quantity) ordered. When i add the join the sum is wrong and seems like things are counted double.

How can i solve this?

```
select
sum(invoices_items.item_quantity) as registration_count,
sum(invoices.total_incl_vat) as registration_price
from  invoices
inner join invoices_items on invoices_items.invoice_id = invoices.id;
```

Comment: do you have `total_incl_vat` column in invoices_items table as well?

Comment: @Alex No. I need a sum from two different tables.

Comment: why would you add a count and a price -- wouldn't you multiply it?  What exactly is your test case here?

Comment: please show your whole data model -- what are the fields in invoices and invoice_items

Comment: note, it is convention to use singular for tables -- so the table name would be invoice (with each row an invoice) and invoice_item (with each row an invoice item)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you join each row of an invoice is as often in the result as it has items. That will cause the sum for the invoices to grow.

If you just want the two sums in one row you can use a `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause and subqueries.

```
SELECT (SELECT sum(item_quantity)
               FROM invoice_items) registration_count,
       (SELECT sum(total_incl_vat)
               FROM invoices) registration_price;
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems invoice items have more then one record against invoice 
so you can do like that

```
select
invoices.id,
(select sum(invoices_items.item_quantity from invoices_items where invoices_items.invoice_id = invoices.id) as registration_count,
sum(invoices.total_incl_vat) as registration_price
from  invoices
group by invoices.id
```

Answer (score 0):

With your approach, you'll need to aggregate them first before you do the `JOIN`

```
SELECT  t.id, registration_price, registration_count
FROM 
(SELECT id, SUM(invoices.total_incl_vat) AS registration_price FROM invoices GROUP BY id) t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT  invoices_id, SUM(invoices_items.item_quantity AS registration_count FROM invoices_items GROUP BY invoices_id) tt 
ON tt.invoices_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id WITH ROLLUP;
```